# Merge two xml files using SAXParser by avoidingg duplicates nodes and adding the new attributes if the node is duplicate In Java Code

Tags: xml, merge

I need help in merging two xml files in java, where if the any new mbean tag is there in file2.xml i should add and if the a 100% duplicate node should be ignored then if the existing node had axtra attributes i need to merge only the attribute but not complete node again.

```
file1.xml
<system name="" ostype="DummyOs" version="1">
    <mbean component="CIM" type="" mbclass="" cimclass="DummyClass1">
        <attribute id="Manufacturer" type="text" value="" />
    </mbean>
    <mbean component="CIM" type="" mbclass="" cimclass="DummyClass2>
        <attribute id="Manufacturer" type="text" value="" />
    </mbean>
</system>

file2.xml
<system name="" ostype="dummyOs" version="1">
     <mbean component="CIM" type="" mbclass="" cimclass="DummyClass1">
        <attribute id="Manufacturer" type="text" value="" />
        <attribute id="New_Manufacturer" type="text" value="" /></mbean>
    <mbean component="CIM" type="" mbclass="" cimclass="DummyClass2>
        <attribute id="Manufacturer" type="text" value="" />
    </mbean>
</system>

output.xml
<system name="" ostype="DummyOs" version="1">
    <mbean component="CIM" type="" mbclass="" cimclass="DummyClass1">
        <attribute id="Manufacturer" type="text" value="" />
        <attribute id="New_Manufacturer" type="text" value="" /> 
    </mbean>
    <mbean component="CIM" type="" mbclass="" cimclass="DummyClass2>
        <attribute id="Manufacturer" type="text" value="" />
    </mbean>
</system>
```